# Loading multiple MIT-Scheme files

Tags: mit-scheme

I am running MIT-Scheme on Ubuntu Linux. I am trying to get the proof-assistant from the MIT Press book "The Little Prover" "compiled". I tried to load three Scheme files from the MIT-Scheme CLI. It seems that when the EOF on the first file was encountered, the other two files were not compiled. What should I do differently in order to compile all three files?

Thanks,

Vasily

Answer (score 0):

Just use three different commands, or a `PROGN` like I have done here:

```
> (progn 
      (load "FILEPATH 1")
      (load "FILEPATH 2")
      (load "FILEPATH 3"))
```